# 100% accuracy in classification with LIBSVM- What could be wrong?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I am building a model for classifying malignant breast tumors using LIBSVM. Here is the algorithm I am following:

1. Use Backward-elimination for feature selection.
2. Calculate C and gamma for each set of features using grid search.
3. Derive the most optimal C and gamma using 10-fold cross validation.
4. Using the above steps, find the best possible subset of features and the maximum accuracy.

The problem is that I am getting a 100% accuracy on a 80:20 dataset using LIBSVM. I've not excluded any feature, and I am NOT training and testing on the same data. Any hints where I could be wrong? Here are some other relevant information:

```
cost = [2^-10, 2^-8, 2^-6, 2^-4, 2^-2, 0.5, 1,
        2, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5, 2^6, 2^7, 2^8, 2^9, 2^10];
g = [2^-10, 2^-8, 2^-6, 2^-4, 2^-2, 2^-1, 1,
     2, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5, 2^6, 2^7, 2^8, 2^9, 2^10];
most optimal C = 1;
most optimal gamma = 9.7656e-04;
Accuracy on 50:50 test:train dataset: 98.5337%
Accuracy on 70:30 test:train dataset: 99.5122%
Dataset used: University of Wisconsin breast cancer dataset (682 entries).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: You didn't complain about the other two data sets; the 100% accuracy is reasonably consistent with those.  What makes you think you *should* have a lower accuracy?

Let's look at the counts of misclassification:

```
50:50 data set -- 5 / 341 errors
70:30 data set -- 1 / 205 errors
80:20 data set -- 0 / 136 errors
```

The 80:20 results are sufficiently consistent with your prior results: your accuracy has increased to (apparently) something over 99.8%.

Demanding maximum accuracy from your training suggests that it may well retain all features, with a distinct danger of over-fitting.  However, since you apparently find that the first two data sets are acceptable, I intuit that the data set is highly self-consistent.  I find that consistency odd from my experience, but you don't describe the data set's properties, or even give us samples or a useful link to check.

Comment: It is a pretty standard data set. Sorry for commenting late, but here is the link:                                                                                                                   https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data                                                                                              The description: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.names

Comment: "pretty standard data set" is a question-begging term; I don't think I've ever met one.  :-)  Are there particular vectors you expect to see mis-classified?  Have you checked the complexity of the model, apart from still having all of its features?

Comment: Hey man, I am pretty new to ML. Can you elaborate on how do I check the complexity of the model?

Comment: Can you access the coefficients of the trained model?  If so, examine them out to see how many of the features have significant contribution to the scoring function -- say at least 10% for some borderline classification vector.